# Django template indentation guideline

Tags: django, templates, indentation

There is PEP 8 for Python, but I haven't seen a preferred indentation guideline for django templates.

What I mean is, I normally indent blocks like this:

```
<span>outside</span>
{% if condition %}
    <span>within condition</span>
{% endif %}
<span>outside</span>
```

While this looks good on the editor, but it will look crap on view source like this:

```
<span>outside</span>
  <span>within condition</span>
<span>outside</span>
```

It would even look worse within the HTML indentation, see below:

```
<div>
    <span>outside</span>
    {% if condition %}
        <span>within condition</span>
    {% endif %}
</div>
```

will become:

```
<div>
    <span>outside</span>
        <span>within condition</span>
</div>
```

While I agree having better layout in editor is way way more important, but I also get paranoid about the generated messy HTML source code.

Comment: A potential fix would be django has an option to reduces a level of indentation within blocks after templates are generated.

Answer (score 8):

I am currently following my own convention in django template guideline for **consistency** matter. The rule is simple:

1. Django tag **does NOT** increase the indentation level
2. HTML tag **does** increase the indentation level

It does not matter how many nested Django Tag you have, you should still on the same level of indentation. I consider this as the *trade off* for putting logic in templates which should be minimized if possible to avoid confusion.

```
<html>
<body>
  <ul>
    {% if condition %}
    {% for item in menu_item %}
    <li>{{ item }}</li>
    {% endfor %}      
    {% endif %}
  </ul>
  <main>
    {% block content %}
    <p>Hello World</p>
    {% endblock content %}
  </main>
</body>
</html>
```

#### Side note

> I am using 2 spaces for HTML indentation, because HTML tends to have a very deep nested.
>
> For Vim user, please note that the syntax is not `html` but [`htmldjango`](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1487)
>
> Thus my `~/.vimrc` looks something like:
>
> ```
> autocmd Filetype htmldjango setlocal ts=2 sts=2 sw=2 expandtab
> ```

Comment: One problem for not indenting django tags is you cannot visually see the logical block, given that's what we see 99.9% of the time comparing to viewing source of the page.

Comment: Yes, that's the trade off we have to pay. In return we have a cleaner HTML. I usually avoid a deep nesting of Django tags to a certain level. Once it reach the limit, I will try to find a way to refactor the code or creating a custom template tag, such as `{% render_menu %}`, which makes it readable.

Comment: Problem with flatten Django tags is the same as any structured language, once the code gets more complicated it is very hard to read and parse and even harder to spot or avoid errors in the logic. Your html is not less clean by having additional indentation. Excessive indentation in html response can be removed with a django middleware if really needed. In any case browsers already re-indent lines in their debugging tools.

Answer (score 1):

Depending your editor, there are ways to set a specific indent width for HTML files.

As for the Django tags, it is actually a good thing not to not add a indent level. See that example:

```html
<ul>
    {% for item in items %}
        <li>{{ item }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Would be rendered like so:

```html
<ul>
        <li>Bacon</li>
        <li>Ninja</li>
        <li>Tumbleweed</li>
</ul>
```

And we do not want the two levels of indent. Instead:

```html
{% block content %}
<ul>
    {% for item in items %}
    <li>{{ item }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: But this is not going to completely solve my problem, have another read. BTW, I use vim.

Comment: I'm afraid I didn't full understand your problem then. What's bothering you ? And as for the editor, you could always set a specific ident style too.

Comment: Hi, the generated HTML source code will get screwed up indentation, I am a little bit annoyed about ti because it doesn't look professional.

Comment: I don't believe this could be a bad impression. But some do (apparently). Again you should **not** keep the tags indent levels as in my example: that is not how they were designed (to avoid loops to create another level of indent for example). Instead put your HTML tags on the same level as their Django tag parents, if any.

Comment: I thought about that putting the template tags same level as HTML parent tags, but it's not clear when you have nested blocks, plus if you have a big block you will need to scan each line for a match close tag.

Comment: I hear you. See the last part of my update. As for the conditional blocks (eg. *if*, *for*), I personally use blank lines to separate them (but you can use Django comments as well).

Answer (score 0):

My apologies for reviving an old question, but I think the way Emacs' [web-mode.el](https://web-mode.org/) indents Django templates deserves a mention here:

```html
{% block content %}
    <div
        id="1"
        class="fancy"
    >
        {% if link %}
            <a href="{{ link }}">
                Click here
            </a>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

As you can see, it indents both Django tags and HTML tags, as well as multiline HTML tags. It supports `<style>` and `<script>` tags too. In fact, I like this behavior so much that I created [DjHTML](https://github.com/rtts/djhtml/), a standalone indenter and a pre-commit hook that uses the same indentation rules as web-mode.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is more of a personal preference and what is easy to read and easy to understand in the future (my time limit is "after six months") would be a better alternative than some cookbook recipes. What I use is a two type approach, not just for Django templates but for any language that accepts free formatting of the code. As such I format not critical portions as just left justified block of lines which is an admittedly eyesore but I tend to just ignore them so I can focus on important parts which is extensively indented, preferably in general single action per line and indented at each semantic group change thus all parent/child grouping, nested elements etc. are visible with just one look only.

```
{% if error_message %} 
<p>
<strong>{{error_message}}</strong>
</p>
{% else %}

<table border>
    <tr>
        <td>
            {{degerlendirme.adi}}
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table border>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Tip
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{ tip }}
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Açıklama
                        
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{ degerlendirme.aciklama }}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <form action="{% url 'perf:degerlendirme' degerlendirme.id %}" method="post">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{ form }}
                <input type="submit" value="OK" />
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
{% endif %}
```

I usually use Eclipse and there are several good HTML editing tools that you can install into that environment. I try to use them, but prefer to depend solely on indentation for ease of reading/coding/analysis cycle. That is mainly because I regularly need to use other editors, mostly vi. In this case if I rely mainly on Eclipse or whatever IDE I was using for understanding the code vi, nano or other text editors would make my life miserable.
As one of my professors said in a classroom, lots of years ago, spaces are free and tabs are even cheaper. 
One last note; Once I needed to remove all white space from a Django template that was creating enormous nested tables in order to improve run time performance. Such might be needed for certain cases. In similar situations it is better to keep one working copy and generate runtime copy from that by a script or tool. I know that, there are some HTML de-clutter tools. In my case, tools I tried corrupted the template and I needed to perform that operation by hand.